# Recursively scrape data from every table found on pages using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following piece of code which scrapes a named table from a single web page:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import csv

filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Football Data\\test" + ".txt"

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    f.write("")
    f.close()

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        titles = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        print 'titles:', titles.extract()[0]

        rows = sel.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tbody//tr')

        for row in rows:

            print 'date:', "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'result:', "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_home:', "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_away:', "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'info:', "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip(), "".join( row.css('.info::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print 'rating:', "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'incidents:', ", ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print '-'*40

            date = "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            result = "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            team_home = "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            team_away = "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            info = "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            rating = "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            incident = " ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip() + ','
```

I then have some code that will scrape multiple pages of the same website and grab the text content of articles:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal3"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Articles"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Articles',)), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self,response):
        paragraphs = response.selector.xpath("//p").extract()
        text = "".join(remove_tags(paragraph).encode('utf-8') for paragraph in paragraphs)
        print text        


execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal3'])
```

What I would really like to do though is grab the data from any table encountered on any page. The code example at the top will only work if the table on a scraped page is called "player-fixture", which it wont be on every single page scraped.

Before I start trawling the HTML on the site looking for which branch of pages are going to have tables named particular things, is there anyway that Scrapy can grab the data from any table encountered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the `id` of the `table` to have different possible values, you can use the `or` operator on your xpath to catch all possible scenarios.

e.g. `'//table[@id="player-fixture" or @id="other-value"]//tbody//tr'`

If there too many possible values, you can try anchoring on a more static variable such as a `div`.

e.g. `//div[@att="value"]/table/tbody/tr`